# Create list can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python

I would to like to create a list programmatically based on following variables:

```
a = 'a'

b = 'b'

c = 1

d = 2

ab =  a + b + c + c

ac = list(ab)
```

But I am getting following message:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: Is there something unclear about not being able to concatenate an integer to a string?

Comment: `ab = a + b + str(c) * 2` or `ab = a + b +  str(c) + str(c)`

Comment: In python, `1` is not the same thing as `'1'`, and they can't be treated as though they are

Comment: you can concat two strings together with `+` and you can add two numbers to gether with `+` but python doesnt know what to do when you try to add a string to an int. Hence the error. So you would need to convert the ints to strings. However i suspect thats not really waht you want at all

Comment: to add values to a list, see the [`append()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) (technically, you add references to values).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  How did you expect this code to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
ab =  a + b + c + c
```

with

```
ab = [a, b, c, c]
```

Comment: is it possible to have an array with different types in c#? obviously not!

Comment: @PeymanMajidi: This question is about Python. In a Python list you can mix any listable types.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing a + b + c + d
but a is an string and c is a int. You cannot add a string with an int and you get Type error.
try that:

```
a = 'a'
b = 'b'
c = '1'
d = '2'
ab = a+b+c+d
ac = list(ab)
```

you will get ac = ['ab12']

Comment: When you use `list` on a string, it will separate each character into a single element. `ac` should equal `['a', 'b', '1', '2']` in your example.

Comment: you wont......`ab` is a string which is really just a `list` of chars. So passing `ab` to list will return a list of the individual elements of `ab` giving `['a', 'b', '1', '2']` to `ac`